# I have a problem about YouTube API with ESP8266

Tags: api, arduino, youtube, esp8266, nodemcu

I try to make youtube subscribe counter but it a problem with youtube api library here the error message

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

The sketch name had to be modified.
Sketch names must start with a letter or number, followed by letters,
numbers, dashes, dots and underscores. Maximum length is 63 characters.
C:\Users\Um Sythat\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino-youtube-api-master\src\YoutubeApi.cpp:95:11: error: DynamicJsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5. Please see arduinojson.org/upgrade to learn how to upgrade your program to ArduinoJson version 6

  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;

           ^

C:\Users\Um Sythat\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino-youtube-api-master\src\YoutubeApi.cpp: In member function 'bool YoutubeApi::getChannelStatistics(String)':

C:\Users\Um Sythat\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino-youtube-api-master\src\YoutubeApi.cpp:95:20: error: 'jsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope

  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;

                    ^

C:\Users\Um Sythat\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino-youtube-api-master\src\YoutubeApi.cpp:97:10: error: 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject' has no member named 'success'

  if(root.success()) {

          ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
Invalid library found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\libraries: no headers files (.h) found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\libraries
Invalid library found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\youtube_control_arduino: no headers files (.h) found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\youtube_control_arduino
Invalid library found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\libraries: no headers files (.h) found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\libraries
Invalid library found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\youtube_control_arduino: no headers files (.h) found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\youtube_control_arduino

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I already download youtube api library and arduino json library and import it to arduino ide I always get error from it i dont know why it gone like this someone who know please help me. I like to hear from you.
And here my code :

```
/*******************************************************************
 *  Read YouTube Channel statistics from the YouTube API           *
 *                                                                 *
 *  By Brian Lough                                                 *
 *  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCezJOfu7OtqGzd5xrP3q6WA       *
 *******************************************************************/

#include <YoutubeApi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

#include <ArduinoJson.h> // This Sketch doesn't technically need this, but the library does so it must be installed.

//------- Replace the following! ------
char ssid[] = "xxx";       // your network SSID (name)
char password[] = "yyyy";  // your network key
#define API_KEY "zzzz"  // your google apps API Token
#define CHANNEL_ID "UCezJOfu7OtqGzd5xrP3q6WA" // makes up the url of channel


WiFiClientSecure client;
YoutubeApi api(API_KEY, client);

unsigned long api_mtbs = 60000; //mean time between api requests
unsigned long api_lasttime;   //last time api request has been done

long subs = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was Previously
  // connected
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(100);

  // Attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  Serial.print("Connecting Wifi: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(ip);


}

void loop() {

  if (millis() - api_lasttime > api_mtbs)  {
    if(api.getChannelStatistics(CHANNEL_ID))
    {
      Serial.println("---------Stats---------");
      Serial.print("Subscriber Count: ");
      Serial.println(api.channelStats.subscriberCount);
      Serial.print("View Count: ");
      Serial.println(api.channelStats.viewCount);
      Serial.print("Comment Count: ");
      Serial.println(api.channelStats.commentCount);
      Serial.print("Video Count: ");
      Serial.println(api.channelStats.videoCount);
      // Probably not needed :)
      //Serial.print("hiddenSubscriberCount: ");
      //Serial.println(api.channelStats.hiddenSubscriberCount);
      Serial.println("------------------------");

    }
    api_lasttime = millis();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch the libraray - it uses

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
```

and the error tells us whats wrong

```
 error: DynamicJsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5 <=== you have probably version 6.x.x installed
```

which is a memory hog. Often one single function is used by libraries and the rest is useless. To solve your problem, you have to

```
downgrade ArduinoJson.h to version 5.13.5
```

The other reason I do not like it, breaking changes in nearly all major releases (real big breaking). So another option you have  (if skilled enough) replace the ArduinoJson functions with

- a lighter JSON library
- or replace it with self written JSON functions - often a simple buffer and some char handling does the trick

[Read the issues and PRs on github](https://github.com/witnessmenow/arduino-youtube-api/) to inform yourself about [missing updates](https://github.com/witnessmenow/arduino-youtube-api/issues/18) and other problems. 
Development stopped March 2018 since then no adaption to the (breaking) changes in the youtube API